# Why Integer object is counting slower than int in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime, operator-overloading

When I run the below code my output is blocking with neither compile time or run time error.

```
Integer count;
count = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
while(count != Integer.MAX_VALUE) count++;
System.out.println("Max Value reached");
```

I understand java doesn't support operator overloading however it is not throwing any error why?

edit: The above code does work however it is taking more time so I want to know why it is taking more time?

I replaced 'Integer' with 'int' and it is returning fast.

Comment: Just wait a little longer.

Comment: Why it should? `count++` work because of autoboxing

Comment: A debugger and a breakpoint would have quickly convinced you that it wasn't blocking and shown you why, without the need for a SO post...

Comment: @Tim I see a potential problem in the way it works and it needs to be addressed. I would like to know the clear picture of the things happening in the background so that it would be better for the new Java version to fix these loopholes in the future.

Comment: You're right that the debugger wouldn't have shown you why this was slower than if `count` was an int; you hadn't edited your question to add that detail when I made my comment.  But it certainly would have shown that nothing was blocking.  Either way, there's no "loophole"; the Java compiler allows you to write `count++` rather than rejecting it because the `++` operator hasn't been defined for `Integer`.  You could write your own compiler that disallows autoboxing and fails compilation on `count++`, but I don't know why you would, or why you'd want that "fix" in the next version of Java.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Honestly I don't want my code to fail for compilation error on count++ however it is strange to know that a new object is created by the current JVM for this simple counting. Since originally I had a different idea about the code I created this post and if I've convinced the way how JVM works I won't have reported this at all.

Comment: @Tim If it involves more waiting time when we mix Objects with primitive types (thru autoboxing) then why are you justifying that there is no loop-holes in java???

Comment: If you're not happy with this amount of flexibility (most people would say "user-friendliness") in a language, I recommend you never look at JavaScript, Ruby, or Groovy.  But it's not a loophole ([definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loophole)), it's just a well-documented case where the compiler will allow you to use shorthand for a more-complicated operation to make your code easier to write and to read.  Which is *exactly* what `++` is on ints, and you were happy to use that; maybe you should be using `count += 1`, or better, `count = count + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

`count` is an `Integer`. `count++` is the equivalent to `count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1)`. The slowness is due to the box/unboxing.

Comment: I assigned an initial value to the variable count. So we have now a single object 'count' with its internal value as Integer.MIN_VALUE. In the statement count++; we are updating the object by itself then why compiler is creating new object?? I should use the original object only correct? I don't understand why it is replaced in the above form you mentioned.

Comment: `Integer` is immutable, just like `String`, so `++` can't update the object itself any more than String concatenation changes the original String.  `++` can only create a new `Integer` with a value equal to one more than the original `Integer`'s `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that int and Integer are basically the same. Far from it, but the compiler makes it appear so because it adds all the necessary conversions behind your back (the automatic conversion between primitive int and java.lang.Integer wrapper is called autoboxing).

When you wrote this code:

```
Integer count;
count = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
while(count != Integer.MAX_VALUE) count++;
System.out.println("Max Value reached");
```

What javac did generate for your code is the equivalent of:

```
 Integer count;
 count = Integer.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
 while(count.inValue() != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
     count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1);
 }
 System.out.println("Max Value reached");
```

(I just explicitly added the calls the compiler implicitly inserts - with java versions below 5 you would have needed to explicitly write it in this way because there was no autoboxing in those versions).

So there are calls to .intValue() and .valueOf(int) generated. Take a look at the javadocs for .valueOf(int); it creates a new *Integer* object for almost every call. That means when you use Integer instead of int, there are about 4 billion objects created in the loop instead of just incrementing a counter. Thats why its taking longer.

Comment: When I see the running process in 'Task Manager' the memory used is not increasing linearly. So which means the created objects were garbage collected side by side? Will it really create a new object per iteration?

Comment: @Athiruban Of course the Integer becomes garbage collectable as soon as a new value is assigned to the variable (at each loop iteration). You can use command line options to actually see when it garbage collects (-verbose:gc)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected. The loop runs 4.3 billion iterations, so will take a while to terminate.

Comment: Yes it took more time however when I change 'Integer' to 'int' it is returning fast. Sorry I thought it is blocking.

Comment: @Athiruban Because when it's `Integer` it's also doing implicit boxing or I guess rather unboxing at each loop iteration.

Comment: @peter.petrov It will also do boxing each iteration (and create and discard about 2^32 - 256 objects in the process)

Comment: As mentioned by Steve Kuo and others the statement 'count++' is replaced by Java compiler and that is creating new object each time. Do you have idea why we need to create new object though I am using a single variable 'count'??? Please share your comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's not blocking, it's busy. It hasn't reached `System.out.println("Max Value reached");` yet.

When you use `int` instead of `Integer`, it's faster as there's no boxing/unboxing involved. When you use `Integer` it's also doing implicit boxing, or I guess rather unboxing (here: `count != Integer.MAX_VALUE`), at each loop iteration which slows it down.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is autoboxing (and unboxing), you didn't write code with error. only the loop takes long time to terminate. You have to wait a little more.

You can read about autoboxing here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html